# Remove the insert delay after entering insert in a read-only file

Tags: insert-mode

When entering or doing any command mode modifications to a read only file for the first time you will get the warning

```
W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file
```

That's fine, but this also introduces a second or two delay before the action actually *happens*.

Is there a way to disable this delay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: there is no way to disable this, or to  shorten the 1 second timeout :-( The good news is that you can just start typing while this message is being displayed, the characters are still inserted.

---

Longer version: from `misc1.c`:

```
    if (msg_silent == 0 && !silent_mode)
    {
        out_flush();
        ui_delay(1000L, TRUE); /* give the user time to think about it */
    }
```

The `msg_silent` is set when using `:silent`, for example `:s/./a/` will give the warning, but `:silent s/./a/` won't. There is, as far as I can see, no way to start insert mode silently (`:silent startinsert` doesn't work).

`silent_mode` is set with `-s`, from `vim(1)`:

```
   -s          Silent  mode.   Only  when started as "Ex" or when the "-e"
               option was given before the "-s" option.
```

But as the help message says, this only works when using Vim as `ex`, and not when using it as `vim`.

Answer (score 4):

You could simply `:set noro` before doing the modification. This should prevent the warning.

Comment: `au BufEnter * set noro`

Comment: See [my comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43081/48490) for a more elaborate version of this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an excerpt from my `~/.vimrc` that approaches the OP's issue a bit differently.  I didn't want to lose the warning message, which I find rather useful, but the hardcoded delay has simply become too annoying over time.  It also interfered with some mappings that I use for the insert mode completion.

Here's the vimscript code:

```
" Get rid of the annoyingly long hardcoded delay when insert
" mode is entered for the first time on a read-only file, while
" emulating the original message that it rather useful
"
augroup vimrc-no-readonly-delay
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter *
    \ if &readonly
    \ |   set noreadonly
    \ |   echohl ModeMsg
    \ |   echo "-- INSERT --"
    \ |   echohl NONE
    \ |   echon " "
    \ |   echohl ErrorMsg
    \ |   echon "Warning: Changing a readonly file"
    \ |   echohl NONE
    \ |   redraw
    \ |   sleep 500m
    \ | endif
augroup END
```

Of course, you can adjust the `sleep` value to fit your prerefences.  Having the emulated message displayed for 500 milliseconds (`500m`) works fine for me.

---

Below is an **improved version** of my vimscript code, which also avoids repeating the same warning message.  For example, it happened when <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> was used to begin a new line above the cursor in a freshly opened read-only file.

Here's the improved vimscript code:

```
" Get rid of the annoyingly long hardcoded delay when insert
" mode is entered for the first time on a read-only file, but
" emulate the original message that it rather useful and avoid
" having it repeated, for example when using SHIFT-O
"
augroup vimrc-no-readonly-delay
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter *
    \ if &readonly
    \ |   set noreadonly
    \ |   let s:readonly = v:true
    \ | else
    \ |   let s:readonly = v:false
    \ | endif
  autocmd InsertEnter *
    \ if s:readonly
    \ |   let s:readonly = v:false
    \ |   echohl ModeMsg
    \ |   echo "-- INSERT --"
    \ |   echohl NONE
    \ |   echon " "
    \ |   echohl ErrorMsg
    \ |   echon "Warning: Changing a readonly file"
    \ |   echohl NONE
    \ |   redraw
    \ |   sleep 500m
    \ | endif
augroup END
```

---

Actually, after using this vimscript code for some time, I figured out that unfortunately not all original warning messages are emulated and displayed this way.  For example, no read-only warning is displayed when deleting a few lines in visual mode right upon opening a read-only file.

I spent some time trying to fix it using the `FileChangedRO` autocommand event, and I also tried using timers, but the end results were far from satisfactory.  I'll see to implement a patch for `vim` that makes the timeout for the read-only warning configurable, and submit the patch upstream.